# Having issue with CPU boosting on AMD

Tags: ubuntu, intel, cpu-usage, amd

Background.  I am the author of an application that emulates a Tandy Color Computer (Motorola 6809).  This app has been stable for five years.

Lately I have noticed some strange CPU boosting issues with the application.

The application is written for Linux and has been tested on both X64 and ARM64 platforms.

Recently on intel platforms the frame per second governor which has always been 60 FPS is now oscillating between 56 & 64.

I always keep old builds in my library and so launched a two year old working version and it too is exhibiting this same FPS fluctuating behavior.

Since my old executables have not recompiled themselves something must have changed with the kernel CPU scheduling.  GUESSING!!!

I then tested this on a clean build of Ubuntu 22.04 but on an AMD platform.

The FPS counter is rock steady on 60 fps.  Both systems are Ubuntu 22.04 with the kernel 6.5.

On the AMD system I then noticed the emulated motorola 6809 frequency would not raise to the requested frequency (unless it was set very low).

It was at this point I noticed my app on the AMD system was not causing the CPU to boost away from the minimum base clock frequency, regardless of how much load I created in the emulator.  The system is a laptop and is on AC power with cpufreq-info showing the cpu governor is set to "Performance".

On the Intel system monitoring the application in htop shows the app is multi threaded and the CPU emulation thread was running at 109%+.  On the AMD system it too shows it is multi threaded but the CPU emulation thread would never exceed 99%.

I have to admit this is the first time I have used an AMD system for development but I was surprised at this difference.

I would appreciate any ideas on how I might investigate these issues further.

```
Issue 1 - fluctuating FPS on Intel
Issue 2 - refusing to boost on AMD
```

Update:  I transferred the old and new executables to another desktop system running Ubuntu 22.04.03 but with kernel 5.15.0.94 and everything is working as expected.

I'm leaning further to a recent change in the kernel!!!

Comment: Just to be clear, your emulator is *mostly* single-threaded? I.e. the AMD CPU has plenty of idle cores? I know current Intel CPU's beat AMD in single-core performance due to higher boosts, while AMD CPU's generally offer more cores/$.

Comment: @MSalters: You guessed it!  Plenty of free cores.  The emulator is the only thing running apart from htop, Xorg (system stuff). I'm really getting the impression something in the kernel scheduler changed because everything (especially the old versions) were running fine on both platforms only a short time ago.  But then again i'm guessing.

Comment: If the AMD CPU has the thread consistently at 99%, why do you expect it to boost? CPU boosting is a feature to handle short activity spikes. In those cases, the core is fairly cold (literally) and a short CPU boost won't cause it to overheat.

Comment: @MSalters.  I suppose it doesn't need to boost but it should rise above the minimum of 1.2GHZ to at least the rated 2.38GHZ.  Boost is from 2.39 - 3.99GHZ.  But it remains between 1.2-1.4 GHZ.

Comment: Oh, that's not "refused to boost". That's "stuck in power saving mode". Still, it's not on-topic here. It's a bug in Ubuntue, not your code. The Intel bit might be; I don't know how your code tries to maintain 60 FPS. But we can't answer that unless you manage to produce a *small* example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @MSalters: "Boost" can be sustained long-term for single-threaded code that doesn't make too much heat for the system to dissipate.  The "base" clock (for a given number of cores active) might be something it can sustain even in the worst case (2x 256-bit FMAs per clock cycle, like Prime95).  Anything that makes fewer tranistors switch every cycle makes less heat per clock and thus can run at higher clocks for the same TDP (power).  (See [Why can't my ultraportable laptop CPU maintain peak performance in HPC](//stackoverflow.com/q/36363613) for an Intel example where this *isn't* the case.)

Comment: @WalterZAMBOTTI: What laptop are you using?  Is it a "gaming" or "workstation / productivity" laptop, or ultra-portable?  Have you cleaned the fans recently?  Do other 100% CPU-load applications sustain high boost clocks for extended periods, like minutes?  It's unsurprising that a desktop can sustain max boost with a snigle-threaded workload; desktop power budgets are typically at least 65W, vs. laptops being 45W to 15W depending on the model, or even lower on models with only passive cooling.

Comment: @PeterCordes The AMD laptop is a Ryzen 5 4500 U. It does have a low TDP but I know it was "boosting" fine a few weeks ago.  Because I conducted performance tests for my emulator on this system and it sustained a constant 505mhz 6809 frequency.  Now it struggles to maintain 230mhz and keeps throttling back to the  min of 1.78mhz.  That's a large contrast over a short period!

Comment: @MSalters OK so that's not boost.  So what is the base "boost" actually called?

Comment: The term you want to google here is "P state", I think.